# Upload directory to aws EC2 linux server fail

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, scp

I can upload a single file to the AWS EC2 linux server, but not able to upload a directory. I keep getting Permission denied error. The **ssss** folder is under **kolgate-playground**, I think my path is correct because I can upload a **untitled.txt** under **kolgate-playground folder**

`ray@Roxane kolgate-playground % scp -r "ray.pem" ssss  ec2-user@ec2-18-191-59-50.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:new`

`ec2-user@ec2-18-191-59-50.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).`
`lost connection`

Answer (score 0):

The command should be (note the use of `-i` and `-r`):

```
scp -i "ray.pem" -r ssss  ec2-user@ec2-18-191-59-50.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:new
```